# What is the best way to hardcode a table of constants in Java?

Tags: java, android, constants

I am creating a crypto portfolio app that calls multiple different API's which use different id's for the cryptocurrencies. As such I need a table that maps an API and a cryptocurrency to a string id that is used in that particular API for the cryptocurrency. Preferably, this would also go the other way (map API and string id to a cryptocurrency). What is the best way to hardcode such a table in Java? (Without needing to create for example a Guava Table and manually inserting all values)

Comment: You need to more clearly explain your data structure. Is it three parts or two: API, currency, ID?

Comment: By “hard-code”, do you mean all the values are known at compile-time, and they do not change at runtime?

Comment: @BasilBourque it is three parts, and all values are known at compile-time and don't ever change at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
  public static final Map<String, String> MY_MAP= Map.of(
      "apiname1", "id-01",
      "apiname2", "id-02");
```

If you also need a mapping the other way around, create a function the creates a new map with the keys and values swapped.
If the API is not a string but another class, be sure to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`.